# Error [[ not found in bash

Tags: bash

```
  e=1  
    if [[ e -eq "1" ]]
            then
            echo "1"
            e=2
    fi

    if [[ e -eq "2" ]]
        then
        echo "2"
        e=1
    fi
```

Hi, I am trying to do this simple program in bash, but I have this error:

> scriptCTH_v2.sh: 109: scriptCTH_v2.sh: [[: not found

Can you help me please?

Comment: How are you calling the script? You need to be explicitly using `bash`, not `sh` or another shell

Comment: I am calling this program writing "sh scriptCTH_v2.sh"

Comment: Call it with `bash scriptCTH_v2.sh` and it should work

Comment: I guess that you also want to be comparing `$e -eq 1`, rather than `e`.

Comment: Yes, it works! How it's possible? I'd like to understand!

Comment: I've added to the answer in the linked question - hopefully that makes things clear.